# Storing Long value in byte[] in spring

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, type-conversion

Below is the code snippet:
I am trying to upload a file having long as a datatype and storing that file size in a byte array.

```
long fileSize = uploadedFile.getSize();
byte techGuide[] = new byte[fileSize];
```

I got the build error:
error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int

Please suggest what i am missing and what should i try?

Answer (score 1):

```
Path path = uploadedFile.toPath(); // File.toPath.
```

Repair of your code:

```
// Not needed for readAllBytes.
long fileSize = Files.size(path);
if (fileSize > Integer.MAX) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("File too large");
}
byte[] techGuide = new byte[(int)fileSize];
```

New code:

```
byte[] techGuide = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

Arrays are limited by their int index. You would need to cast the fileSize to an int (and check an overflow). However `Files.readAllBytes` does that for you, throwing an OutOfMemoryError of > Integer.MAX - 8.

Comment: Code-only answers are low quality answers.

Comment: @TaslimOseni when you are right, you are right; added